# Animated background using two images in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I would like to continuously switch between two images after some interval lets say(200 ms) to get a animated flashing/blinking like appearance in the background. I have only managed to get still image for now.

This following code is the child window of a main program which is calling the function Refresher.

Main function:

```
def rad_alarm(self):

   self.alarm = Tk.Toplevel()
   self.alarm.geometry('1024x600')

   #self.alarm.title("Alert")
   vFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 30)

   #self.center(self.alarm)
   self.alarm.overrideredirect(1)

   #self.alarm.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash');

   radfilename = PhotoImage(file = "radio1.png")
   self.alarm.background_label = Label(self.alarm, image=radfilename)
   self.alarm.background_label.pack()

   bcklbl = Label(self.alarm, text = str(bck), bg="black", fg="Yellow", font=vFont)
   bcklbl.place(x = 825, y = 300, width=140, height=40)       


   cpslbl = Label(self.alarm, text = str(counti), bg="black", fg="Yellow", font=vFont)
   cpslbl.place(x = 825, y = 445, width=140, height=40)

   dtlbl = Label(self.alarm, text = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), bg="black", fg="Yellow", font=vFont)
   dtlbl.place(x = 630, y = 140, width=380, height=40)


   button=Button(self.alarm, text="Acknowledge Alarm", command=self.alarm_close, relief=FLAT, bg="black", fg="Red", font=vFont)
   button.place(x = 400, y = 510, width=380, height=80)

   dt=str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

   self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO ALARMS (CPS,BCK,DT) VALUES (?,?,?)",(counti, bck, dt));


   self.conn.commit()

   self.Refresher()
```

Function called for animation:

```
   def Refresher(self):
       sleep(0.1)
       radfilename = PhotoImage(file = "radio2.png")
       self.alarm.background_label.configure(image=radfilename)
       sleep(0.1)
       radfilename = PhotoImage(file = "radio1.png")
       self.alarm.background_label.configure(image=radfilename)
       self.alarm.background_label.after(200, self.Refresher)
```

As I said I am only getting a still image on background instead of flashing/blinking animation. Any idea where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I have added some more details in the question. I hope it will clarify the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask a question. You've told what you're trying to do, but haven't explained what part of the problem you're struggling with. What sort of help do you need?

Comment: I am only getting a still image on background instead of flashing/blinking animation. Any idea where I am going wrong ?